# Riemannian Hausdorff distance between two conjugacy classes in a compact Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry

I am interested in the distance between two conjugacy classes in a group like $SO(n)$. However let's consider $U(n)$ for simplicity. My conjecture is that the Hausdorff distance between the conjugacy classes of $\Lambda_1$ and $\Lambda_2$, both of which are diagonal matrices, is given by the distance of the eigenvalues $(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$ and $(\lambda^{(2)}_1, \ldots, \lambda^{(2)}_n)$ as elements in the homogeneous space $\mathbb{T}^n / S_n$, where the action of the symmetric group $S_n$ on $\mathbb{T}^n$ is by permutation of the coordinates. Thus by translation invariance, the closest element to $X$ in the conjugacy class of $Y$ is any one that can be simultaneously diagonalized with $X$. However I don't know how to prove this plausible statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Diagonalization gives a map $f\colon U(n)\to \mathbb{T}^n/S_n$.
The map $f$ is also the projection to the orbit-space of the $U(n)$-action by conjugacy on $U(n)$.
Hence $f$ is a submetry;
i.e., $f(B_r(M))=B_r(f(M))$ for any matrix $M$.
Hence your statement follows.

Comment: Do people really say *submetry*?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.4650

Comment: I guess your claim that $f$ is a submetry can be proved by Lipschitzness of the exponential map at every point on $U(n)$, which in turn can be proved by Baker-Hausdorff lemma. Is this how you think about it?  

Comment: $DEITY, now Lipschitzness!... :P


Comment: +1 for appeal to deity.

Comment: @John, the projection to the orbit space of isometric group action is always an submetry.  

Comment: @Anton, I guess it depends on how you put a Riemannian metric structure on the orbit space right?